# Using condition in Reactjs components

Tags: reactjs

In my study example of code every button must display different text on click depending on condition writing in parent component.

```
 handlerButtons=()=> {
    switch(this.props.id) {
        case "id1": this.setState({text: "Text 1"}); break;
        case "id2": this.setState({text: "Text 2"}); break;
        case "id3": this.setState({text: "Text 3"}); break;
        case "id4": this.setState({text: "Text 4"}); break;
        case "id5": this.setState({text: "Text 5"}); break;
        default: this.setState({text: "Text default"}); break;
    }
}
```

Why does the click on any button display only default text? What is wrong with condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually missing `onClick` on the most import place - the button it self . You're also checking the value of `this.props.id` though the id isn't in your props. Do the following changes:

```
class MyButton extends React.Component { 
    onClickHandle = (e) => { this.props.onClick(e) }
    render() {          
        return <button id={this.props.id} className="mybutton" onClick= {this.onClickHandle}>{this.props.label}</button>;    
    }
}
```

Change ButtonList to this:

```
class ButtonsList extends React.Component { 

    render() {

        return(
        <ul>
            {buttons.map((button)=> <MyButton id={button.id} label={button.label} onClick={this.props.handlerButtons}/>)}           
        </ul>
        );  
      }
    }
```

And lastly, change your handler:

```
handlerButtons=(e)=> {
    switch(e.target.id) {
        case "id1": this.setState({text: "Text 1"}); break;
        case "id2": this.setState({text: "Text 2"}); break;
        case "id3": this.setState({text: "Text 3"}); break;
        case "id4": this.setState({text: "Text 4"}); break;
        case "id5": this.setState({text: "Text 5"}); break;
        default: this.setState({text: "Text default"}); break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Irina I've managed to solve it, need a few changes. Update answer in a minute

Comment: @Irina Updated .

Comment: This will have to be on Sunday then .. if you want give a new link to the updated code and I’ll tell you what’s missing . Also please explain what exactly is not working .. when I tested the label has changed on each button

Comment: You have two typos , first -> `HandleButtons` should get `e` as input parameter, like my example above , right now you're not getting anything as parameter. Second -> in `ButtonList` component you're missing an `s` in onClick :  onClick={this.props.handlerButton**s**} @Irina . Change this and the code will work

Answer (score 1):

Its because, You are passing the function to `MyButton` component but not using it, means there is no onClick handler attached with button element that's why.

Whatever the data/function we pass in props they will be just the entries of the object, we need to use them somewhere.

Like this:

```
<button
    id={this.props.id}
    className="mybutton"
    onClick={this.props.click}
>
        {this.props.label}
</button>
```

**Suggestion:** Use the same name for handler function when passing in props to avoid confusion.

[Working Code.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mGOjQx)